# Netbook won't boot to Lubuntu GUI after using Live USB creator programs & setting aside 1GB for persistence

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb, tty, persistence

Have downloaded and installed Lubuntu 14.04 LTS, recently (without persistence) & it works fine, aside from not saving settings.

When I try to download & install the same, with a 1MB set aside for persistence, using the USB creator programs such as UNetbootin, I'm prompted to log-in which I wasn't prompted to do w/ my non-persistence-enabled Live USB.

Plus, after a short time, the following text starts cycling through:

[image: lubuntu-14.04-desktop-1386]

The previous Live USB, I created using one of the Live USB creator programs (without persistence enabled) went straight to the desktop GUI with no log in required.

Even tried the manual method of formatting & partitioning a separate USB listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Setting_Up_Your_USB_Stick I'm assuming I only have to do the partitioning & Creating the "casper-rw" File System parts?

Also tried to use iso on an external HD as outlined here but couldn't find the HD when trying to point to it w/ the pre-installed,"Create live CD" program as shown here: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/how-install-linux-usb-flash-drive#null

The limited USB ports on the netbook are the limiting factor holding me back, I suspect. I have to use a USB splitter device & its not externally powered so the netbook can't see it.

Hardware: 
    Lenovo IdeaPad S10 4333-36U Netbook
    Intel Atom N270 1.6GHz
    1GB DDR2
    160GB HDD
    10.1" WSVGA
    Windows XP Home

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my question here: [Trouble With Persistence After Making a USB Live Thumb Drive Using Pendrivelinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248477/trouble-with-persistence-after-making-a-usb-live-thumb-drive-using-pendrivelinux) The answer that solved my problem was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/248576/527764). This method it allows you to start setting persistence at a very low-level. Takes longer to boot, in my case, but it works